# Bootstrap responsive table click to expand div not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap responsive table.Table inside button click expand and collapse specific div.In desktop view its work fine but mobile view its not working.

**CSS**

```
.expandClass[aria-expanded=true] .fa-chevron-circle-right {
display: none;
}
.expandClass[aria-expanded=false] .fa-chevron-circle-down  {
display: none;
}
```

**html**

```
<table id="respTableId" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive"  
style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:50%;">Column 1</th>
<th style="width:50%">Column2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId1" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId1">
Test Data 1
</div>
</td>

<td>data2</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId2" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId2">
Test Data 2
</div>
</td>

<td>data3</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId3" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId3">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId3">
Test Data 3
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="respTableId" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive"  
style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:50%;">Column 1</th>
<th style="width:50%">Column2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId1" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId1">
Test Data 1
</div>
</td>

<td>data2</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId2" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId2">
Test Data 2
</div>
</td>

<td>data3</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId3" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId3">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId3">
Test Data 3
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My doubt is desktop view above code works fine.But in mobile view it not working. I try another way for below javascript code but also facing same issue.

**Javascript**

```
function showHideDiv(id)
{
var x = document.getElementById(id);
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want it will work with out any css or js code, just with bootstrap library

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table id="respTableId" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive"  
style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:50%;">Column 1</th>
<th style="width:50%">Column2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId1" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId1">
Test Data 1
</div>
</td>

<td>data2</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId2" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId2">
Test Data 2
</div>
</td>

<td>data3</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId3" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId3">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId3">
Test Data 3
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="respTableId" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive"  
style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="width:50%;">Column 1</th>
<th style="width:50%">Column2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>data1</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId1" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId1">
Test Data 1
</div>
</td>

<td>data2</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId2" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId2">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId2">
Test Data 2
</div>
</td>

<td>data3</td>
<td> <a class="expandClass" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseId3" role="button" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseId3">
Click to View / Hide 
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
<i class="fa  fa-chevron-circle-down" style="font-size:1.5em;"></i>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseId3">
Test Data 3
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a live demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mohcin2Bn/w3pbtozh/1/)